# iOS - MPMoviePlayer is not allowing to pause the video

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I am working on MPMoviePlayerController.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
NSString *fileURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/FileName.mp4", documentsDirectory];
myMoviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileURL]];
myMoviePlayer.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[[myMoviePlayer view] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, getReadyMoviePlayerView.frame.size.height)];
[myMoviePlayerView addSubview:[myMoviePlayer view]];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinished:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification object:myMoviePlayer];
myMoviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
myMoviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = NO;
myMoviePlayer.fullscreen = NO;
myMoviePlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
[myMoviePlayer prepareToPlay];
[myMoviePlayer play ];


-(void)moviePlayBackDidFinished:(NSNotification *)dict{

    if (dict.object == myMoviePlayer) {

        NSInteger reason = [[dict.userInfo objectForKey:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey] integerValue];
        if (reason == MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded){

            [myMoviePlayer prepareToPlay];
            [myMoviePlayer play];
        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that, The play and pause button is not working. I am not able to pause the video by using MPMoviePlayer Controls.

This problem is with both OS that is iOS 7 and iOS 8 also.

Is there any solution to pause the running video.

Thank you

Comment: Is it just pause or play or all movie buttons don't respond? (like forward backward). Your code seems fine.

Comment: Also, where is moviePlayBackDidFinishedFromGetReady method?

Comment: What is `myMoviePlayerView`?

Comment: @SamB: Only Play/Pause Button is not working. And Now I have edited the problem. I forgot to add that method. Actually we are using taht method to play video in loop.

Comment: @Larme: myMoivePlayerView is another UIView in main view In which I have added myMoviePlayer.